# Android: Creating a TextView programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create a `TextView` (with Java code, not xml) with `layout_width=fill_parent` ?

The `TextView` should be editable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i don't understand question wrongly,you need to create an `EditText` programatically.then,Try using:

```
EditText et=new EditText(context);
et.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

**EDIT :**

Import for LayoutParams:

```
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
```

Comment: You understand it ok. what is the import for LayoutParams ?

Answer (score 4):

Its not a TextBox, its [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) in Android.

Anyway, you can create it run time using:

```
EditText ed = new EditText(this);    // Create a new EditText

// Setting the type of input that you want
ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);       

// setting height/width for your editText
ed.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

EditText et = new EditText(context);// this gets you a new textbox

//assuming you're in eclipse when you hit the . after et you'll see all its various properties that you can set as you like.

then when you're ready you either set it as the setContentView(et);// here it's the only thing on the screen

or

add it to whatever layout you have already set.

Answer (score 0):

Create layoutParams with appropriate width and height by

> LayoutParams params = //choose appropriate constructor

//beware about right import .

now Create textBox and setLayoutParams

> EditText t = new EditText(this);
>
> t.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: he's asking about EditText, not TextView