# Can we set or edit the content of a com.google.android.gms.vision.text.Text.TextBlock?

Tags: android, textblock

As per Google Documentation of OCR [TextBlock](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/text/TextBlock) it contains these methods.

- getBoundingBox()
- getComponents()
- getCornerPoints()
- getLanguage()
- getValue()

Is there any way to setValue() for TextBlock?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. OCR is engineered to extrapolate text from image content -- it's not intended to recreate text in an image space.

You can always overlay your own textbox though, depending on your use case.

Comment: How can I do that. I just need to display another text if some conditions fulfill.

Comment: It depends on your application. Can't you create a view programmatically? [Like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976990/android-creating-a-textview-programmatically)

Comment: @srv242 see the below answer

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what exactly you need. If you are thinking to change the text of the display which are recognizing by the vision API, then it is possible.

You just need to create another constructor in OcrGraphic class in my case where I am using OCR example from Vision API.

```
private TextBlock mText;
private String cText;

OcrGraphic(GraphicOverlay overlay, TextBlock text, String caption){
    super(overlay);
    mText = text;
    cText = caption;
    .
    .
    .

    // Redraw the overlay, as this graphic has been added.
    postInvalidate();
}
```

And then modify previous constructor

```
OcrGraphic(GraphicOverlay overlay, TextBlock text) {
    super(overlay);

    mText = text;
    cText = text.getValue();
    .
    .
    .

    // Redraw the overlay, as this graphic has been added.
    postInvalidate();
}
```

And in draw method you need to draw the text from your variable

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    TextBlock text = mText;
    if (text == null) {
        return;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    // we replaced text.getValue() with cText that string are set by either constructors
    canvas.drawText(cText, rect.left, rect.bottom, sTextPaint);

}
```

Now you can call through both way, it will work, just use when which is necessary in detector processor as below: (in **OcrDetectorProcessor** class in **receiveDetections** method)

```
OcrGraphic graphic = new OcrGraphic(mGraphicOverlay, item);
// Or use new one for your custom text
OcrGraphic graphic = new OcrGraphic(mGraphicOverlay, item, textValue);

mGraphicOverlay.add(graphic);
```

Please let me know your case exactly what you wanted to do. The accepted answer is also correct but this is a trick outside vision API.